# C++ Program Compiler Error: No Matching Function

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

I'm using a linked list to implement a concordance program. I am getting the following compiler error when trying to compile the program with g++:

concordancetest.cpp: In function 'void build_list(std::ifstream&, char*)':
concordancetest.cpp:65: error: no matching function for call to ‘Concordance::insert(char*&, int&)'
concordance.h:22: note: candidates are: void Concordance::insert(char (&)[9], int&)

Below is the code I have written:

Header File:

```
#ifndef CONCORDANCE_H
#define CONCORDANCE_H

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

const int MAX = 8;

class Concordance
{
    public:
        //typedef
        typedef char Word[MAX+1];

        //constructor
        Concordance();

        //destructor
        ~Concordance();

        //modification member functions
        void insert(Word& word, int& n);
        void remove(Word& word);
        int get_count(Word& word);

        //constant member functions
        int length() const;

        //friend member functions
        friend std::ostream& operator << (std::ostream& out_s, Concordance& c); 

    private:
        struct Node
        {
            Word wd;
            int count;
            Node *next;
        };
        Node *first;    

       Node* get_node(Word& word, int& count, Node* link);   
};

#endif
```

Implementation Code:

```
//class definition
#include "concordance.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <cstring>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

Concordance::Concordance()
{
    first = NULL;
}

Concordance::~Concordance()
{
    Node *temp;
    while(first != NULL)
    {
        temp = first;
        first = first -> next;
        delete temp;
    }
}

void Concordance::insert(Word& word, int& n)
{
    Node *prev;

    if(first == NULL || strcmp(first -> wd, word) > 0)
        first = get_node(word, n, first);
    else
    {
        prev = first;

        while(prev -> next != NULL && strcmp(prev -> next -> wd, word) > 0)
            prev = prev -> next;
        prev -> next = get_node(word, n, prev -> next);
    }
}

void Concordance::remove(Word& word)
{
    Node *prev, *temp;
    prev = temp;
    if(prev -> wd == word)
    {
        first = first -> next;
        delete prev;
    }
    else
    {
        while(strcmp(prev -> next -> wd, word) > 0)
            prev = prev -> next;
        temp = prev -> next;
        prev -> next = temp -> next;
        delete temp;
    }
 }

int Concordance::get_count(Word& word)
{
    while(strcmp(first -> wd, word) != 0)
        first = first -> next;

    return first -> count;
}

int Concordance::length() const
{
    Node *cursor;
    int len;

    len = 0;
    for(cursor = first; cursor != NULL; cursor = cursor -> next )
      len++;
    return len;
}

Concordance::Node* Concordance::get_node (Word& word, int& count, Node* link)
{
    Node *temp;

    temp = new Node;
    strcpy(temp-> wd, word);
    temp-> next = link;
    temp -> count = count+1;
    return temp;
}

ostream& operator << (ostream& out_s, Concordance& c)
{
    Concordance::Node *cursor;

    out_s << "Word" << setw(10) << " " << "Count" << endl;
    out_s << "--------------------" << endl;

    for(cursor = c.first; cursor != NULL && cursor->next != NULL; cursor = cursor-> next )
      out_s << cursor-> wd << setw(10) << " " << cursor -> count << endl;

    if(cursor != NULL)
      out_s << cursor-> wd << setw(10) << " " << cursor -> count << endl;
    out_s << "--------------------" << endl;

    return out_s;
}
```

Test Program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
#include "concordance.h"
using namespace std;

void read_word(ifstream& in_file, char array[]);
void build_list(ifstream& in_file, char array[]);

int main()
{
    char file_name[100];
    ifstream in_file;
    char array[MAX+1];

    cout << "Enter a file name: ";
    cin >> file_name;

    in_file.open(file_name);

    build_list(in_file, array);

    in_file.close();

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}   

void read_word(ifstream& in_file, char array[])
{
    char ch;
    int i = 0;

    in_file.get(ch);

    while(isalpha(ch) && !isspace(ch))
    { 
        if(i > MAX-1)
        {
            while(!isspace(ch))
            in_file.get(ch);
            break;
        }

        ch = tolower(ch);
        array[i] = ch;
        i++;
        in_file.get(ch);
    }

    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        cout << array[j];
    cout << endl;

}

void build_list(ifstream& in_file, char array[])
{
    Concordance c;
    int count = 0;

    while(!in_file.eof())
    {
        read_word(in_file, array);
        c.insert(array, count);
    }

    cout << c;
}
```

Comment: your code is trying to pass a pointer where a reference to an array is expected; you can't do that.

Comment: For reference with the [just use standard library](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/369bdd3c5a5de272) advice

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The type of `char array[]` is `char *`, so when it looks for a matching function, none is found. You can fix this by using `typedef char* Word;` and enforcing your max length inside the functions that require it.

Comment: change `void insert(Word& word, int& n);` to `void insert(Word word, int& n);` There's no point in passing your array by reference